# Various errors while scanning for folders

Tags: python, unicode, directory, python-os

Please do not mark as duplicate as I have looked at the other questions with this error and I still can't figure it out.

I am making a basic scanner that scans a directory given to it and it deletes all sub directories that are older than 90 days. Here is the code:

```
import os, sys
import time
import shutil
from  Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog



now = time.time()
home1 = os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(initialdir=desktop, title="Select folder to scan from: ")
path = path.encode('utf-8')

for x in os.walk(path):
    for folders in x:
        while os.stat(folders).st_mtime < now - 90 * 86400:
            q = raw_input('Folder(s) found. NOTE: This will delete all directories or subdirectories in the folder. Do you want to remove?(y/n) ')
            if str(q) == "y" or str(q) == "Y":
                shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)
                print 'Successfully deleted folder(s)'
            elif str(q) == "n" or str(q) == "N":
                print 'Folders not deleted.'
                sys.exit()
        else:
            print 'No folder(s) over 90 days'
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Bill/Desktop/limitScanner/scanner.py", line 20, in <module>
while os.stat(folders).st_mtime < now - 90 * 86400:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Edit: When I use my program on a folder with multiple sub folders such as the desktop folder, it gives me the following error: `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified` and the name of the first folder.

I am using `python 2.7.13`. Can anyone please help? Any help is widely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.walk` returns a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`. Your current approach iterates on the 3-tuple which in the second iteration gives a list of directory names `dirnames`.

However, you are only interested in the `dirnames`:

```
for _, dirs, _ in os.walk(path):
    for folder in dirs:
        ...
```

Comment: My program just seems to freeze when doing this

Comment: @Bill It is stuck in the `while` loop. You should use an *if* block instead.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
import os, sys
import time
import shutil
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

now = time.time()
home1 = os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(initialdir=desktop, title="Select folder to scan from: ")
path = path.encode('utf-8')

for _, x ,_ in os.walk(path):
    for folders in x:
        if os.stat(os.path.join(path,folders)).st_mtime < now - 90 * 86400:
            q = raw_input('Folder(s) found. NOTE: This will delete all directories or subdirectories in the folder. Do you want to remove?(y/n) ')
            if str(q) == "y" or str(q) == "Y":
                shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)
                print 'Successfully deleted folder(s)'
            elif str(q) == "n" or str(q) == "N":
                print 'Folders not deleted.'
                sys.exit()
        else:
            print 'No folder(s) over 90 days'
```

I adapted the `os.walk(path)` output as Moses said, changed the `while` to `if` and added `(os.path.join(path,folders)`, so `os.stat(...)` can find the folder in question.

```
for _, x ,_ in os.walk(path):
    for folders in x:
        if os.stat(os.path.join(path,folders)).st_mtime < now - 90 * 86400:
```